# What guarantees a photonic quantum gate to be unitary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, quantum-computer, unitarity

So in my course of quantum computation i came across this question that "What guarantees a quantum gate to be unitary?" i was specially curious about photonic quantum gate.

At first i thought that maybe unitary is not something that is guaranteed by any special phenomena but its inherited by the math behind quantum physics and that we use to describe any physical operation with an unitary operator but is it really the answer?

Answer (score 1):

A quantum logic gate is not *guaranteed* to be unitary, but it is *designed* to be unitary so that it preserves information. This is generally achieved by preventing the system of qubits on which the logic gate is operating from interacting with its environment, so that wave function collapse (which is a non-unitary process) does not occur. This isolation of the system from its environment is never $100\%$, so any practical quantum logic gate will occasionally exhibit non-unitary behaviour - this is one of the sources of errors in quantum computing.

When we intentionally want wave function collapse to occur then we apply a "measurement" - but this is not usually counted as a quantum logic gate.

You *can* design a logic gate that is not unitary because it throws away information. Classical AND and OR gates, for example, are non-unitary because their input is two bits and their output is only one bit.